Using OpentelemtryAppender or Using grafana|Context Variable- Link Trace to logs and Logs to Trace
I am trying to achieve to link

Trace to logs and Logs to Trace.

Using OpentelemetryAppender,

Logs are being sent without traceID and spanID being appended in log message.
But trace_id and span_id is being added as context attribute as shown in screenshot.

Wondering How to extract the context attribute with or without customer query
Note: trace_id is not label but context variable so I can link them to button with trace_id
Customer Query now working
{service_name="${__service.name}", trace_id={${__trace.trace_id}}}

